# Convert boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 to string with precision

Tags: c++, boost, precision, boost-multiprecision

In my code I want to have a function which performs some calculations based on boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 and returns string as a result with some precision, but the question is how I should set the precision ? e.g. If the precision is 9, then I expect the following results for the following numbers:

for `2345.12345678910111213` I expect string  `"2345.123456789"` but I have  `12345.1235`

for  `1.12345678910111213` I expect string  `"1.123456789"` but I have  `1.12345679`

So it always returns my exact number of characters provided to str() function with round. I know that I can do it like e.g. this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << my_value;
return ss.str();
```

or use cout(but this is not my case) or do some find on string to find "." and take only 9 characters after it, but can I do it in an easier way ? maybe in boost is some function to do it correctly ?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>

namespace bmp = boost::multiprecision;

std::string foo_1()
{
    bmp::cpp_dec_float_100 val{"12345.12345678910111213"};
    return val.str(9);
}

std::string foo_2()
{
    bmp::cpp_dec_float_100 val{"1.12345678910111213"};
    return val.str(9);
}

int main() 
{
    auto const val_1 = foo_1();
    auto const val_2 = foo_2();
    
    std::cout << "val_1: " << val_1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "val_2: " << val_2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

online version: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HTAHsE5ZE3tgK9kf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
return val.str(9);
```

To:

```
return val.str(9, std::ios::fixed);
```

You will get the expected strings.